# How do I bring a single function into the current namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Suppose I want to use the `std::max` function in my namespace `A`. How would I do this?

```
namespace A {
void fun()
{
  double x = std::max(5.0, 1.0); // I don't want to have to write the std::
}

void fun()
{
  using namespace std;
  double x = max(5.0, 1.0); // I don't want to have to use the using directive to introduce the entire namespace
}

}
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: `using std::max;`  Then whenever you call `max`, it'll call `std::max`.. unless explicitly stated otherwise such as `foo::max`. http://ideone.com/RpTTAn  I leave this as a comment because it's a simple answer. I don't need the points.

Comment: @Brandon posting answers in comments is [against site policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).  I think that is a dumb policy personally, however moderators can and do go through deleting all comments which are not inline with that policy; including comments containing answers.  So, I have posted an answer although if you want to take the credit and post an answer yourself then ping me and I'll delete mine

Comment: @MattMcNabb wow.. did not actually know such a thing could possibly be against the rules :S Thanks for letting me know. I like your answer btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "import" individual symbols by naming them in a `using` declaration:

```
namespace A
{
    using std::max;
```

This means that `A::max` is defined and designates the same function as `std::max`; so attempts to look up `max` in `namespace A` will find the intended function.

(This is an *Answer* version of Brandon's comment on the original post)